# How to check the internet connection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to make sure the user always stays logged and have no idea how to do that.

In the same way as supercell games log off user and restart game...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a solution, Maybe there are others...
It is about making an http request and check if we are receiving something.

In a first time, import `using System.Net;`

Copy-Paste this method:

```
public string GetHtml(string link)
 {
     string content = string.Empty;
     HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
     try
     {
         using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
         {
             bool isGood = (int)resp.StatusCode < 299 && (int)resp.StatusCode >= 200;
             if (isGood)
             {
                 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                 {
                     char[] cs = new char[80]; //Limiting the array to 80
                     reader.Read(cs, 0, cs.Length);
                     foreach(char ch in cs)
                     {
                         content +=ch;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch
     {
         return "";
     }
     return content;
 }
```

and finally call the method and check result

```
string HtmlText = GetHtmlFromUri("http://google.com");
     if(HtmlText == "")
     {
         // No connection
     }
     else
     {
         // success connection
     }
```

good luck for the future

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public bool CheckInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        if (new System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com/").Result == "")
        {
           return false;
        }
        else
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: creative.... :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite an overhead to me to actually send out a http request and receive content.

Why not simply use a simple [`Ping`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ping.html) like e.g.

```
public InternetConnectionCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isConnected;
    public bool IsConnected => isConnected;

    // by default use an interval of 500ms for the pings
    [Min(0.1f] public float timeout = 0.5f;
    // As default use e.g. CloudFlare DNS 1.1.1.1
    public string tatgetHost = "1.1.1.1";

    // If Start returns IEnumerator Unity automatically runs it as a Coroutine
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // Huh?! -> This is okey in an IEnumerator as long as you yield somewhere within
        while(true)
        {
            // Start an async ping
            var ping = new Ping(targetHost);

            // Wait for the timeout to finish (at the same time this is oir ping interval)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeout);

            // Your ping either succeeded or timed out
            isConnected = ping.isDone;
        }
    }
}
```

Then another class can simply check the `IsConnected`.